# What is diffrence between gradient and slope with exibition?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want know really what is diffrence between **Gradient** and **slope** ?

Can somebody explain it insightly with a example.
**Somebody show me with visual (without math) sample, a sample in real world not with math equation and explanation.**

Appreciate pay attention and help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradient is a mathematical term that is equal to the slope in one dimension. In more than one dimension it is no longer possible to talk about a general slope - but he gradient will give you a vector value essentially describing the $n$ slopes needed to describe the general $n$-dimensional case.